# how to enable ajax load bootstrap menu

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I used bootstrap to implement a side menu, and it works fine.
html code as following:

```html
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
    <div class="menu_section">
        <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Main menu <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav child_menu">
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/admin/home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/admin/admins/1/own_profiles">profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost/admin/admins/1/approve_requests?type=send">My request </a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I change to use ajax method to load this part, it cannot work. 
I can see 'Main menu' in the browser but it cannot expand. I inspect the source there is no problem in its html.

I guess bootstrap needs to do some initialization after html is loaded, so the static content works fine, but for the ajax load method, this part is not initialized, that is the possible reason.

But I don't know which API can be used, could anybody give some support or guideline for that?

Thanks

Comment: "When I change to use ajax method to load this part, it cannot work"...well please show us that code, and explain the problem and/or error messages you're getting. Then we can try and fix it. We can't fix what we can't see. But in response to your later comment, if the menu functionality in bootstrap depends on some javascript in the bootstrap JS file, then yes you'll have a problem when loading it over ajax, unless you wait to include bootstrap.js until after the ajax completes. Why do you want to load your menu via ajax, though? Seems an odd requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved.
I made a mistake, I copy menu code from a template "gentelella", and I find it is not a bootstrap nature menu implementation.

It has own menu implementation code, and I find a init_sidebar() at build/js/customer.js, it needs to call this routine after update menu.